# Error when populating field in URL from MS Access form using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, url

I added a button to my Access form to generate an image from a confidential web application. The URL contains a drop-down field for year, a text box for SFN (six-digit  unique ID when combined with year), and a button to search for the image.  Using values from the record currently listed in the form, the code below successfully populates the year drop-down field and seemingly correctly populates the SFN field; a six digit string appears in the box.

If I leave in the last line to click the search button (ImageDisplayButton) I get an error message from the website that reads "Please enter a valid SFN". The SFN entered looks correct, but I get the error message even when I comment out the last line and click the search button myself after the SFN has been populated by the code. When I manually enter the same number and click search, the image is returned without error.

I understand it's difficult to resolve issues like this without access to the URL. However, I appreciate any suggestions.  I was wondering if somehow the string included invisible characters (e.g., quotes), but I don't know how to test this.

```
Private Sub IMAGED_Click()

    Set browser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    browser.navigate ("https://www.confidentialWebApp.com")
    browser.StatusBar = False
    browser.Toolbar = False
    browser.Visible = True
    browser.Resizable = False
    browser.AddressBar = True

    Dim yearVal As String
    Dim SFNVal As String
    yearVal = Mid(B_SFN, 4, 4)
    SFNVal = Mid(B_SFN, 8, 6)

    browser.Document.getElementById("YearListBox").Value = yearVal
    browser.Document.getElementById("SFN_TextBox").Value = SFNVal
    browser.Document.getElementById("ImageDisplayButton").Click

End Sub
```

Comment: SFN_TextBox possibly has one or more event handlers which validate the entry - these may not be fired when you insert the value using VBA.  See if you can fire the required event(s) so the handler script picks up/validates the value.

Comment: I have only ever had to code web page fill-in once. My code to fill in elements is different. `oBrowser.Document.all.Item("subAcctLoginName").Value = "alaskadot"`

Comment: Thanks for these comments.  How do I know what the events are to fire them?  Is this something I can find in the source code for the web page?

Comment: You can check the length of string in SFNVal variable to determine if there are non-printing characters. `Debug.Print Len(SFNVal)`. But I doubt this is cause of issue.

Comment: I'd start by looking at the textbox (right-click >> Inspect) and see what you can figure out from that.